# Jquery how to retrieve / replace value in <span> <tr> <td> value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are more than one TR TD, same class name given in a table used for formatting without ID given.

I would like to seek help for jQuery. How can I retrieve / replace `<td>` content in the span id = payment_currency_text,  class="formdata element?

1) To set a variable, store as `SGD`, getting from second set of TR TD.
2) Replace `SGD` to `EUR`.

Note : The system used Jquery version = v1.4.2

I tr to used below syntax but no luck :

```
alert(jQuery("#payment_currency_text tr.find(.formdata)").val());
alert(jQuery("#payment_currency_text").next('.formdata').val());
alert(jQuery("#payment_currency_text tr td.formdata").val());
alert(jQuery("#payment_currency_text").find(".formdata").html());
```

... (tr td child)

```
<tr>

  <td class="prompt" align="left">     
    Region* 
  </td>

  <td class="formdata" align="left">
     Asian 
  </td>
</tr>

<span id ="payment_currency_text"> <!--- There is a SPAN tag, with ID given  --->
<tr>
  <td class="prompt" align="left">     
     Payment currency* 
  </td>

  <td class="formdata" align="left">
     SGD   <!--- How i can set a variable to hold SGD, then replace to EUR?  --->
  </td>
</tr>
</span>
```

Comment: span as sibling of tr?? thats not valid HTML

Comment: Fix the HTML, then provide details of what you've tried and where specifically you're stuck.

Comment: `$(.formdata).html("your text here")` ?

Comment: Hi there, the question is updated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

to target `td.formdata` inside `span`.Try this:

**To get:**

```
 var currency=$('#payment_currency_text .formdata').html();//currency will be SGD here
```

**To set:**

```
 $('#payment_currency_text .formdata').html('EUR');
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but im just want to getting the data inside the SPAN tag and replace a new one.. eg SGD to EUR in SPAN ID = payment_currency_text

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. You probably need to spend some time [learning jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/).

Comment: @PeterBoughton: yes i am very confused about what OP is asking.

Comment: Everything you need to know is described in the jQuery docs. Read http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ and http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

Comment: Hi there, i try to used some syntax but no luck, can anyone help?

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Answer (score 1):

If you know that its always going to be a specific child you can use the :nth-child() selector.

```
var setter = $("tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").text();

$("tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)").text("EUR");

alert(setter)
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/87V9v/

Comment: Hi there, The child TR TD is dynamic, no specific child note show on the screen, that why im try to used span ID to just focus the TR TD child.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the html inside the td, use like this

```
$(".formdata").html("some text or tags here");
```

If you want to get the text inside those td, use like this

```
$(".formdata").each(function(){
  $(this).html();
 });
```

**Edit**

```
$("#payment_currency_text").find(".formdata").html()

$("#payment_currency_text").find(".formdata").html("some text or tags here");
```

Your html structure has some problem, you cant enclose `tr` inside span. `tr` should be the child of `table`. So change your html accordingly.

```
 <table>
    <tr>

        <td class="prompt" align="left">
            Region*
        </td>

        <td class="formdata" align="left">
            Asian
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="payment_currency_text">
        <td class="prompt" align="left">
            Payment currency*
        </td>

        <td class="formdata" align="left">
            SGD
            <!--- How i can set a variable to hold SGD, then replace to EUR?  --->
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Then you can use the above code for getting the elements and values.

Comment: Anoop, OP has two td elements with class `formdata`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar may be he wants to change all the td s with those class name. IS it?

Comment: Yes, there are more than one TR TD, using same class name and no ID given.

1) To set a variable, store as SGD, getting from second set of TR TD. 

2) Replace SGD to EUR.

Comment: Hi there, it show NULL when i used $("#payment_currency_text").find(".formdata").html(), my jquery version is v1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can replace the inner HTML of an element like so

```
$('.class-name').html("Some html in here");
```

However, be careful because this will replace the HTML for all classes of this name.

Comment: Hi there, i would like to retrieved and replace the SGD to EUR, under SPAN tag, the rest of the table tr td will remain as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text()` to get the data (plain text) as well as replace existing data with new one. If your replacement is HTML, you can use `html()`

```
var data=$('td.formdata').text();
alert("The value is"+data);
$('td.formdata').text("New Data");
```

Comment: See comments on [Anoop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840872/jquery-how-to-retrieve-replace-value-in-span-tr-td-value#22840931).

Comment: Thank for your help, but im just want to getting the value inside the SPAN tag and replace a new one.. eg SGD to EUR in SPAN ID = payment_currency_text

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#payment_currency_text").text("your text");
```

or

```
$("#payment_currency_text").html("your<b>text</b>");
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but im just want to getting the value inside the SPAN tag and replace a new one.. eg SGD to EUR in SPAN ID = payment_currency_text